# Mysql intermittent access denied for user errors

Tags: mysql

Over the past few weeks I have been getting intermittent, Access denied for user 123456'@'mysqldb' (using password: YES) errors.  These errors can appear on all db pages.

While discussing with my client he can be having problems with a particular page while I am not.

My hosting provider says there are no issues with their DB servers.  I am using `mysql_connect("database", "user", "password")` to connect. Wondering how I can determine what the problem is.

Comment: Perhaps this is a DNS lookup issue.  If your server doesn't have a static IP address, cached DNS lookups could cause a connection attempt to the wrong address.

Answer (score -1):

Your `mysql_connect()` function input values are ordered in wrongway.

```
<?php
    $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');

    if (!$link) {

        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

    }

    echo 'Connected successfully';

    mysql_close($link);
?>
```

It looks like you are trying to connect your database. `mysqldb` looks more like database name. and `123456` might be your password but you use it as username I guess.

You must try to connect to database server which is generally named as localhost or some IP.

```
mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password') or die(mysql_error());
```

will show you what the problem is.

Also `mysql_*` functions are deprecated. Use `PDO` or `mysqli_*` instead.

Using `PDO` you can make a `try-catch` structure and see what the problem is about.

```
    try
    {
       $Link = new PDO('mysql:host=server;dbname=database', 'username',
'password');
    }
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e;
    }
```

Comment: sorry about the confusion.  "database" is the full database server address I was just using it to show I was using mysql_connect to connect to db.  I have no problems at all most of the time.  It's just some times it doesn't connect and the error is generated.  I will research PDO and mysqli_*